# Next.js with Typescript: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, shopify, next.js

On a brand new project using `next.js` with `typescript` I am getting the following error, within a functional react component.

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

In the reference of the error, it is actually showing the functional component that state is being used in:
[image: error]

I have reviewed the recommendations at https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

1. I don't think I am breaking the rules of hooks as I am:

   > Call[ing] them at the top level in the body of a function component.
2. I don't think I have two versions of React, I am using `yarn` and I have resolutions added to only use one version of `React` (https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/)

I don't really know what else I can do to trouble shoot this, so I have published the minimal repo to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/coler-j/shopify_playground

Component:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import {
  Layout,
  Page,
  Card,
  Button,
  FormLayout,
  TextField
} from '@shopify/polaris'

export default function App() {
  const [first, setFirst] = useState('')
  const handleFirstChange = useCallback(value => setFirst(value), [])

  return (
    <Page title="Polaris">
      <Layout>
        <Layout.AnnotatedSection title="Form" description="A sample form using Polaris components.">
          <Card sectioned>
            <FormLayout>
              <FormLayout.Group>
                <TextField value={first} label="First name" placeholder="Tom" onChange={handleFirstChange} />
              </FormLayout.Group>
              <Button primary>Submit</Button>
            </FormLayout>
          </Card>
        </Layout.AnnotatedSection>
      </Layout>
    </Page>
  )
}
```

Comment: Any code about your `functional component`?

Comment: yes, sorry linked on minimal example on github, but also posted now too

Comment: I clone your code and run it successfully. Maybe there are something wrong with your developing environment. Change a computer and try it again.

Comment: thanks for confirming @JimJin was worried about that. I am Win 10.

Comment: I'm use win10, too. Maybe your typescript is too old?

Comment: Show us the code that is rendering `App`

Comment: All code is here: https://github.com/coler-j/shopify_playground

Comment: Have a look at this: https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/is-usestate-and-hooks-in-general-supposed-to-work-with-next-js~49a710f0-b7fc-4ff0-8956-d4fa9548a24f

Comment: @ddon-90 thanks, basically the same issue, doesn't work for that user, but works for someone else. I am going to try to run the app in docker or purge any global packages I have installed, and then try again when I have time.

Comment: @JimJin if you want to make an answer that it must be something wrong with my local dev env, I will accept it. I have the code working in docker fine.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: I have to run in docker to get things to work, there is something messed up with my local env and  I have not had time to look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ran into a similar problem after **pushing my *Next.js* project** (which was 100% working) **to Github and then** – almost immediately – **cloning it back to the same computer** (running Windows 10).

While the error dialog was complaining of '*Invalid hook call*', the error watefar in my terminal actually complaints about [invalid directory casing](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-project-dir-casing). I've tried to switch to a few UNIX based terminals, but to no avail.

**I deleted the `node_modules` and `.next` directories and tried the fresh install from a PowerShell. The issue was gone…**

I think what initially caused the issue was that I used a default Windows command line for the first `yarn install` (it starts a little bit quicker than the Windows Terminal and I was impatient) and it somehow did messed the casing. But I'm not sure.

Using a Docker container is definitely a more robust and futureproof solution…

Comment: Simply removing `node_modules` and running `npm install` fixed it for me. Thank you.